# Why doesn't this list comprehension do what I expect it to do?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The original list `project_keys = sorted(projects.keys())` is `[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]` where the following projects were deemed `invalid` this year: 108, 109, 110.

Thus:

```
for project in projects.itervalues():
# The projects dictionary is mapped to the Project class
    if project.invalid:
    # Where invalid is a Bool parameter in the Project class
     project_keys.remove(project.proj_id)  

print project_keys
```

This will return a list of integers (which are project id's) as such:

`[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107]`

Sweet.

Now, I wanted it try the same thing using a list comprehension.

```
project_keys = [project_keys.remove(project.proj_id) for project in projects.itervalues() if project.invalid  

print project_keys
```

This returns:

`[None, None, None]`

So I'm populating a list with the same number as the removed elements but they're `None`s?

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Additionally, why would I use a list comprehension over the `for-if` block at the top? Conciseness? Looks nicer?

Comment: Well, the comprehension clearly *works*, but clearly not as expected. Title updated.

Comment: @Az, as well as those who feel I should not have included an answer amounting to RTFM:  The reason I suggested consulting the docs more is that I see you have been pounding SO pretty hard lately.  There's nothing wrong with that, but while some of your questions are genuine "how do I solve this problem?" (good), others seem to me more like "I don't feel like looking this up; can you guys tell me instead?" (less good, in my opinion).  I meant no ill will; despite what some may think, I'm not anti-newbie, just pro-docs.

Comment: @John Y: I am a bit pressured by time. In addition, the Python docs - while useful for portions I understand well or have used extensively - are still a quite obtuse to me as a beginner. I'm aware of the building blocks I need to move on to a solution but sometimes I find that the docs obscure the path for me. Do you get what I mean? I understand your concern, all the same. Additionally, the stackoverflow.com members have shown me some very interesting ways to deal with problems which has been a `learning` experience. I'm pro-learning ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list comprehension works using side-effects. Just executing it should update project_keys to give the result you want.

```
[project_keys.remove(project.proj_id)
 for project in projects.itervalues()
 if project.invalid]
```

The return value from `remove` is `None`. Assigning the result of the list comprehension to `project_keys` is where you are going wrong.

A simple loop is probably clearer here though. A list comprehension that uses side-effects can be confusing.

However you can solve your problem in a slightly different way:

```
project_keys = sorted(project.proj_id
                      for project in projects.itervalues()
                      if not project.invalid)
```

This keeps the projects you are interested in, instead of removing those that you're not interested in. The example I gave above uses a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, but it would work with either.

Comment: It appears you beat Dirk by 12 seconds, but his is an actual list comprehension, while yours is (as I write this, maybe you'll edit it later) strictly speaking a generator expression and not a list comprehension.

Comment: @John Y: True. :) I'll think about the best way to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Nice edit.  Evidently Dirk decided your fuller explanation makes his superfluous, and my own was both less informative and too snarky, so mine will soon be gone as well.

Comment: @Mark Byers: That's neat! Thanks muchly :)

Comment: Marks' second solution--to make a copy of the list--is much better than to use `remove()` while you iterate over the list. It is risky to modify a collection inside a loop that iterates over its members. It may work as expected or fail catastrophically, depending on the implementation of the list and iterator classes. Even if in-place modification works on `list` s, what happens if someone feeds your code a different kind of collection? Or Python's `list` implementation changes in the next version? Whereas The copy strategy always works, even on immutable collections, like tuples

Comment: @Dan He iterates over `projects.itervalues()` while removing from `project_keys`, so no, he's not modifying what he's iterating on.

Answer (score 4):

You, sir, have misunderstood list comprehensions.

#### What you probably wanted (in words)

> I want to remove all project ids that are invalid.

#### What you wrote

```
project_keys = [project_keys.remove(project.proj_id)
                for project in projects.itervalues() if project.invalid]
```

#### What is actually going on

```
dummy = []
for project in projects.itervalues():
  if project.invalid:
    dummy.append(project_keys.remove(project.proj_id)) #what are you
project_keys = dummy                                   #removing items from?
del dummy
```

#### What is actually going on (now with more "functional")

```
mapped-fun = lambda project: project_keys.remove(project.proj_id)
filtering-fun = lambda project: project.invalid
project_keys = map(mapped-fun, filter(filtering-fun, projects.itervalues()))
```

---

As you can see, list comprehensions are *not* syntactical sugar around `for` loops. Rather, **list comprehensions are syntactical sugar around [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)**: apply a function to all items in a *sequence* that match a condition and get a *list* of results in return.

Here, by function it is actually meant a side-effect-free transformation of input into output. This means that you "cannot" use methods that change the input itself, like `list.sort()`; you'll have to use their functional equivalents, like [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted).

By "cannot", however, I don't mean you'll get error messages or [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html); I mean you are abusing the language. In your case, the evaluation of the list comprehension that happens as you assign it to a variable does indeed produce the intended side-effects -- but does it produce them on the intended variables?

See, the only reason why this can execute without an error is that before this list comprehension, there was *another* list called `project_keys` and it's *that* list you are actually changing!

Lists comprehensions are a result of functional programming, which rejects side effects. Keep that in mind when using lists comprehensions.

---

So here's a thought process you can use to actually get the list comprehension you wanted.

#### What you actually wanted (in words)

> I want all project ids that are valid (= not invalid.)

#### What you actually wanted

```
dummy = []
for project in projects.itervalues():
  if not project.invalid:
    dummy.append(project.proj_id)
project_keys = dummy
del dummy
```

#### What you actually wanted (now with more functional)

```
mapped-fun = lambda project: project.proj_id
filtering-fun = lambda project: not project.invalid
project_keys = map(mapped-fun, filter(filtering-fun, projects.itervalues()))
```

#### What you actually wanted (now as a list comprehension)

```
project_keys = [project.proj_id for project in projects.itervalues()
                if not project.invalid]
```

Comment: Dude, that's pretty damn awesome :)! Mark Bayers' one worked so I checked that as a viable answer (and it was pretty good and it was there earlier). Can't thank you enough for taking the time to spell out the whole thing.

Comment: It's okay. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem